# How to retrieve questions and answers from mysql database by using php files

Tags: php, android

i would like to make a Quiz Application but i have some problems and i am not too sure as to how I should approach them. I am at a fairly basic level for php so was wondering if anyone could help me?

In mysql I have a database with a "Questions" table and "Answers" table.

[The layout of my database on mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFnek.png)

My database contains 20 question with each of them having 4 possible answers as can be seen in the link above.
I would therefore like to select all the questions and display them in a random order along with the multiple choice answers. I'm quite unsure of the coding to use. Through research I think I can use:

RAND() LIMIT 0,19 in order to randomise the questions.

The end of plan is to display the questions and answers in textview boxes on android studio. The user interface design is as follows:
[User interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znqlK.png)

I apologise that i can not give much detail on a solution it is due to my inexperience of PHP. Any help to retrieve questions and answers from mysql database through php files would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about php, but
1. you can create an ArrayList and generate a random number in a range of your total question's id, //if you have 10 questions then 1-10

2. If that id isn't in the array, add it, and get the question from your question table according to the id that you've just generated
3. And also get your answer from the answer table and put it in another array, and then generate other three random numbers for your answers and put in the second array.
4. then generate number from 0 to 3 and for the second array to put the answers in 4 option(TextViews), you might wanna use a switch case approach here. (must be unique, only for each question, you can regenerate the same answers for other questions too)
5. if the users clicks/chooses any of them check with the answer and there you go
  6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this will be very helpful after I have sorted out my php files.

Comment: Would it be better to form the arrays in the php file or to form the arrays in android studio once all the questions and answers have been retrieved from the database?

Comment: I would suggest android studio